# Is there any working todo plugin for Redmine v2?

Tags: redmine, todo

There were couple great todo plugins for Redmine 1.x. However none of them work anymore with v2x series. I looked around and I could not find any update or new todo related plugins for Redmine v2.

I am wondering if anyone knows or has a modified todo plugin that works with Redmine v2x?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://github.com/ande3577/redmine-stuff-to-do-plugin (or other branches on Github)